# Get all referencing entities two levels upstream

Tags: 7, views, entities, blocks

I have three content types. Content Type A, Content Type B and Content Type C.

Content Type A has an Entity Reference field named field_B

Content Type B has an Entity Reference field named field_C

What I want to achieve is create a view that I can use one Content Type C node to display all nodes of type A that reference this node through nodes of type B.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: Yes, I solved it myself. If I remember correctly I was just thinking about the problem in a more complex way than necessary.

Comment: I guess you just used multiple relationships? Maybe you can add your own answer